# Where do I ask questions about specific graduate schools and chances of admission?

Tags: discussion, meta

I am currently a sophomore, but just looking for some statistics on graduate school admissions, and if possible chances tailored to my own statistics.

Comment: You can flag the moderators to migrate your question to meta. I just did it for you.

Answer (score 1):

There are dozens of forums on grad school in general and for schools in specific fields in particular, where you can ask such questions. Try searching Google for "What are my chances of getting into university [X]" and you will find plenty of them.

Whether you will find this exercise useful or not is another question entirely. See: http://forum.thegradcafe.com/topic/23061-before-you-ask-what-are-my-chances/

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that the particular program I am most interested in is a small program that does not post statistics online, but is at a very well-known university nonetheless. So, there isn't really much data to go from - I really don't know anything about my chances, or even if I have a chance.

Comment: Actually, this isn't true. In many academic fields it is *extremely* hard to find information about PhD program admissions. TheGradCafe is a little sparse.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this could be a good question for the main site. I am not sure why it was migrated to meta. It would take a little bit of work to make it clear that your are not asking on AC.SE for your chances for acceptance, but rather how to evaluate your chance for admission. My other concern would be that the question would become a poll type question asking for recommendations of other forums.